# Windows Task Scheduler - Run only during window of time

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a task already set up in the Windows Scheduler (on Win Server 2008).  It works great but it can put a burden on the system during peak hours (when the box is being used for other things).  I currently run the job every 15 minutes.  Can Task Sch. be setup to run every 15 minutes but only during a certain window of time.  So I could set it up to run every 15 min, but only from 5pm to 5am -- and not run at all from 5am to 5pm?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Set a daily schedule starting at 5pm. In the Advanced dialog, click Repeat task, then specify Every=15 minutes, Until:Time=5am.

**Edit:** The above instructions are for Windows 2003 Server or XP. If Windows Server 2008 is like Windows 7, then you can do the same thing through the Triggers tab. Set a daily trigger, Start=5pm, Repeat Task Every=15 minutes, For a duration of=12 hours.
**You don't need to stick with the pre-defined times - you can type into these fields any value you wish.**

Comment: On my Win Server 2008 box, I don't have an "Advanced" dialog.  On the "triggers" tab, I can set the starting time and I have a "Repeat task every", but no "Until" option.  There is a "for a duration of" but those options are 15min, 30min, 1 hour, 12 hours and 1 day.  Not exactly very flexible.  Am I missing something?  Thx.

Comment: @Bryan See my edit. I don't have a 2008 server available, but this is what the task scheduler looks like on my Windows 7 laptop.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out they don't want the process to run for 12 hours, so this is not an optimal solution.  The fact that the trigger page only allows 15min, 30min, 1 hour, 12 hours and 1 day is a bit frustrating...but it's the best thing I can do for now.  thanks for the follow up.

Comment: You don't need to stick with the pre-defined times - you can type into these fields.

Comment: 12 years later and still a valid answer!

Answer (score 53):

For Windows 2008 & above this is what I did:

1. Create task
2. Triggers tab
3. New ...
4. Use the following settings

[image: Schedule]

In this particular example I want to run the task from 12:06 AM to 23:50 PM.

In "for a duration of" I entered the amount of minutes I want it to run for. Actually you could also enter some thing like 23:50:00 in the "for a duration of" field. It will automatically convert it to minutes after you click OK. That was my experience.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer as it shows the exact details of how to enter in custom times/durations.  Who knew this hidden functionality was in the task scheduler?? Surely not me.

Answer (score 12):

In the triggers tab you can add multiple triggers by using the "New" button. See screenshot below.

[image: Windows Task Scheduler Triggers Tab]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set on the the Start field: 5:00:00 AM and on 'for duration of' you have to write '12 hours' or '12:00:00'