# Check timespan which may cross day boundary

Tags: powershell

I have a monitoring script which is executed every 5 minutes by task scheduler. If the script determines there is a problem, an alert condition is raised and a notification email is sent. The script then terminates. All well and good.

I want to define some 'quiet hours' during which time, monitoring still takes place on schedule, but notifications are suppressed. These hours will cross the midnight boundary.

I could do this with something like this:

```
$quietHoursStart = "22:00"
$quietHoursEnd = "06:00"
$timeNow = Get-Date

if ( $timeNow -lt (Get-Date $quietHoursStart ) -and
     $timeNow -gt (Get-Date $quietHoursEnd ) ) {

     Send-NotificationEmail

}
```

That's fine, but if I ever re-define the quiet hours range so that it does not cross the midnight boundary (e.g. 00:00 -> 06:00) , then the notification will always fail since the `if` condition can never be true.

If could add additional tests to see if the range crosses midnight, then have two separate checks to see if current time is 'quiet', but I feel there should be a more elegant solution.

The values for the quiet hours start/end are actually pulled in from an XML config file but for the sake of clarity, the example above uses simple definitions.

EDIT: To clarify; the script must run every 5 minutes, regardless of quiet hours, since it records a log of problems found. Changing the schedule will not achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390617/windows-task-scheduler-run-only-during-window-of-time

Comment: Possible misunderstanding. I need the script to always trigger (so that it can log problems). I just want to suppress the notification during certain hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add comparison between `$quietHoursStart` and `$quietHoursEnd` to check is given interval cross midnight or not.

```
$quietHoursStart = "22:00"
$quietHoursEnd = "06:00"
$timeNow = Get-Date
$TimeOfDay = $timeNow.TimeOfDay

$IsQuietHours = if ( $quietHoursStart -le $quietHoursEnd ) {
    $TimeOfDay -ge $quietHoursStart -and $TimeOfDay -lt $quietHoursEnd
} else {
    $TimeOfDay -ge $quietHoursStart -or $TimeOfDay -lt $quietHoursEnd
}
if ( !$IsQuietHours ) {

     Send-NotificationEmail

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was working on something similar after the OP's comment pointing out the flaw in my (soon to be deleted) answer, but I was having a hard time validating everything in my head. Good job!

Comment: Yep - I think that's probably the neatest way. Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest changing the two `-le` operators to `-lt`? As it stands, if the Quiet Hours End is 06:00, and it is now exactly 06:00, then that will count as a quiet time.

Comment: @dan-gph Yes, it probably would be better that way, but it just very hard to have exactly `06:00:00.0000000` to actually cause any difference.

Comment: @PetSerAl, agreed, but it triggers my OCD :) I guess though you could have exactly `06:00:00.0000000` in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Alain O'Dea's link really does address your need quite well, but from a scripting focused stance I think a better way to approach this (script wise, his link to scheduling the task is probably better) would be to define a starting time, and then a duration. So you want it to start at 10PM and go until 6AM? That's an 8 hour duration. Also, I would test to see if it is in your quiet time, and then invert it with `-Not` (I use the alias `!`)Try something like this:

```
$quietHoursStart = "22:00"
$quietHoursDuration = 8
$timeNow = Get-Date

if (! ($timeNow -gt (Get-Date $quietHoursStart ) -and $timeNow -lt (Get-Date $quietHoursStart ).AddHours($quietHoursDuration)) ) {

     Send-NotificationEmail

}
```

Comment: Will that still work for the case when timeNow is post-midnight but before the end of quiet hours? I think the first IF clause would be FALSE, second clause TRUE, then AND results in FALSE, invert to TRUE and notification is sent...