# Windows Task Scheduler- How to make task run only once before a certain time?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have two tasks set in Windows Task Scheduler right now:

> Light Mode Auto
>
> Dark Mode Auto

The tasks changes the theme on Windows depending if it's night or day. Light Mode Auto runs only once and is set to trigger at 8AM daily, Dark Mode Auto runs only once and is set to trigger at 6PM daily. Both tasks are set to "run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed".

The problem is if I dont use my laptop after 5PM and start my laptop again at 9AM the following day then the Dark Mode Auto task doesn't run until the following morning. However since it's after 8AM, the Light Mode Auto tasks starts to run as well. Both tasks run simultaneously, but for whatever reason Dark Mode Auto takes priority and leaves my laptop on Dark Mode even though it's during the morning/day. Similar issue for Light Mode if I don't use my laptop say after 7AM and start again at 7PM.

Is there a way I can specify for the task to run before a certain time? For example set the "Dark Mode Auto" to run only if it's after 6PM and before 8AM? Or for "Light Mode Auto" to run only if its after 8AM and before 6PM? I'm aware there's an option to repeat the task for a set duration but this is not what I'm looking for as I dont need my task to repeat itself, only need it to run once at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402422/windows-task-scheduler-non-repeating-only-run-during-window-of-time?rq=1). Had to create a simple batch file that is configured to run command only between a given time frame. Afterwards, add this batch file to the task in Windows Task Scheduler.